# Center navbar menu items

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to imitate the menu from [Chobani](http://chobani.com) which is a double menu, I almost there but I cannot make the items get centered on the navbar, anyone have any suggestions? Or if someone have a better idea to do so.

I've tried with .nav-justify also with display: table on navbar-nav class, but this lead to a disorder on the items of the second menu.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
        <ul class="navbar logos-menu pull-left">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x45">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x45">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="submenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="one">
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="two">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 3</a></li>
        </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="three">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7w8megv4/) in JSFiddle

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know why you give me a downvote on my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `nav-justified` like this...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-default">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#four">Four</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav id="submenu">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li>
        <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="one">
          <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 4</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
         <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="two">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 3</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
          <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="three">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
          <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="four">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Four sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Four sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/dX9iCfcI9c